# Filtering whole of hierarchical list with LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, hierarchy

I have a simple hiearchical list of objects "ProductGroups" (IQueryable).
Each "ProductGroup" has a collection of ProductGroups called "Children",an integer ParentId field and a boolean "IsEnabled" field.

```
public class ProductGroup
{
    public int Id;
    public int ParentId;
    public ICollection<ProductGroup> Children;
    public bool IsEnabled;
}
```

I want to be able to return a tree of ProductGroups where "IsEnabled" is true.

At the moment, if I do

```
ProductGroups.Where(x => x.IsEnabled)
```

This returns the enabled products. If I do

```
ProductGroups.Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
```

This returns the roots. I want to be able to return a full tree excluding the disabled items in the neatest way possible (i.e. not using for loops after querying the collection).

```
ProductGroup1 (IsEnabled == true)
    |
    --------- ProductGroup2 (IsEnabled == true)
    |               |
    |               ----------- ProductGroup4 (IsEnabled == false)
    |
    --------- ProductGroup4 (IsEnabled == false)
```

i.e. Return ProductGroup1 with 1 child ProductGroup2

Thanks

Comment: LINQ is always going to return a flat IEnumerable, so what you're looking for (really) is the root of the tree? Is that true? If so, why don't you add a function to ProductGroup that returns the enabled children (only) and use that function along with your root? Or are you indeed trying to get a IEnumerable containing all of the enabled nodes & their children down to the leaves?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact needs with the filtered collection. I'm looking at it as a `View-Model`. And a recursive extension method provides you with a neat way to achieve this filter:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static ICollection<ProductGroup> EnabledWithChildren(this ICollection<ProductGroup> source)
    {
        var result = new List<ProductGroup>();
        foreach (var ele in source)
        {
            if(ele.IsEnabled == true)
            {
                var productGroup = new ProductGroup{Id = ele.Id, IsEnabled = ele.IsEnabled, ParentId = ele.ParentId};
                if(ele.Children != null && ele.Children.Count() > 0) 
                    productGroup.Children = ele.Children.EnabledWithChildren();
                result.Add(productGroup);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }    
}
```

And usage:

```
public class ProductGroup
{
    public int Id;
    public int? ParentId;
    public ICollection<ProductGroup> Children;
    public bool IsEnabled;

    static void Main()
    {
        var filteredProductGroups = ProductsGroups.EnabledWithChildren();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that all of the productgroups will be loaded in memory before filtering. I would like to get EF to do the filtering using some clever LINQ if possible, i.e. against the IQueryable so that only the needed records are returned from the database. My dataset could potentially have millions of records so it is important that I can get EF to filter out records correctly.